# Multiprocess names on Linux

Tags: linux, python, process

I'm using Python's [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) package which conveniently names worker processes on its own. I can access these names for debugging purposes from within my Python script. However, I'd like to do so from the shell and `htop` or `ps -aux` only show the command with which these processes were invoked, which is `python test.py` for *all* processes. Is there a way to get the same process names as below but in dash?

```python
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

class MyWorker:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def square(self):
        time.sleep(30)
        return self.x**2

pool = mp.Pool(4)
nums = [i for i in range(10)]
workers = [MyWorker(x) for x in nums]
tasks = []

for worker in workers:
    pending = pool.apply_async(worker.square)
    tasks.append(pending)
[print(proc.name) for proc in mp.active_children()]
results = [result.get() for result in tasks]
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

this yields

```
ForkPoolWorker-3
ForkPoolWorker-2
ForkPoolWorker-4
ForkPoolWorker-1
```

I know you can go to `/proc/{your_pid_here}/cmdline` if you already have a pid to work with but I'm looking at hundreds of processes so a list like overview is preferred.

Comment: In general [you can pass anything as `argv[0]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051035/10765659). E.g. try `bash -c 'exec -a foo sleep 300' &` and then `ps -aux | grep foo` will show you `foo 300` instead of `sleep 300`. I totally don't know how you can do it in Python, so it's not an answer.

Comment: the multiprocessing package seems to name its processes on its own and I don't know where they are set. It seems to me argv[0] is set when the initial script is invoked and then inherited as workers get forked. Consequently, they all share the same CMD. I'm interested in the process _name_ though.